# Android studio could not read file NAND

Tags: android, android-studio

I have android studio 1.5 installed. OS : Windows 7 .

When I try to run the emulator, I get the following error

> NAND: could not read file
>   C:\Users\appUser\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/system-images\android-23\google_apis\x86/system.img,
>   Invalid argument

I have removed "read only" permission and "hidden" from the AppData folder. Also I ran android studio as admin, still I am getting the same error.

I have Android 6 installed.

[I had asked similar question in android stackoverflow.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/131935/android-studio-could-not-read-file-nand) , but have now deleted it.
[image]

Comment: open sdk manager and make sure under API 23 system images are installed.

Comment: Other than those images related to TV or wear, the Intel Atom image x64 is installed.

Comment: Show me your sdk Manager.

Comment: have added an image @tinysunlight

Comment: Can you use other image?

Comment: I installed the TV image. Still I get the same error when I try to run the emulator from AVD.Edit - was starting wrong emulator. The TV emulator is running fine